# Running SQLite operations in another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a project with SQLite database in Android. I wish to execute few operations on it, for example save a row, read all rows from table, delete row etc. I want to execute that operations in another thread. My question is: which multitasking method should I use? I was thinking about one class, something like database manager, which has some methods that represents operations I wrote above. I don't have an idea how to make it easy and simple. Maybe Service will help me with this task or maybe should I use another class for one operation, for example one AsyncTask class for one operation? I am waiting for all of Your answers and advices. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would think a background service is a bit overkill for simple database operations.

For the most part, I'd use a ListView with a [Cursor Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html%20%22Cursor%20Adapter%22http://) for list type data that was required to scroll.  For smaller data sets, maybe< 10 rows, I'd just fetch the data in the UI thread.

For more complex operations, say checking the state of the DB on startup, or removing a set of rows, I would write an AsyncTask for each purpose.

I have been using [ORM Lite](http://ormlite.com/) for just about all my Android SQL lite projects for a while now and I just follow the convention of a singleton DatabaseManager and create methods within the manager class that require custom queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsyncTask for this.In its doInBackground() method you can do all the operations required like adding to the contents to the table etc.

Add this in your Activity.

```
private class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    DataBaseHelper db=new DataBaseHelper(context);
    protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        db.addData(.....);
    }
}
```

And the below is the DataBaseHelper class.

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  // Database Name
  public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "YourName.db";

  // table name
  public static final String TABLE_DATA = "your Table name";
  //  Table Columns names
  public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
  public static final String KEY_NAME = "DataName";
  public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "Content";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE_DATA = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DATA + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CONTENT + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DATA);

  public void addData(DataBaseModel dataBaseModel) {
    SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, dataBaseModel.getDataName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_CONTENT, dataBaseModel.getContent()); // Contact Phone
    // Inserting Row
    db1.insert(TABLE_DATA, null, values);
    //Toast.makeText(context, "New row added, row id: " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    db1.close(); // Closing database connection
  }

  // Getting single data
  public String getData(String dataName) {
    String data=null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //SQLiteDatabase db2=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_DATA, new String[]{KEY_ID,
                    KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTENT}, KEY_NAME + "=?",
            new String[]{dataName}, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    try {
         data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        data=null;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return data;
}
```